# jQuery to dynamically add table rows

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to dynamically add table rows on change of my select 
I already wrote a script that actually does this, but the system is not dynamic yet.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#noOfSegments").change(function(){
    var counter=${#noOfSegments}.val();
    for(i=0; i<counter; i++){
    var row = $("<tr><td>"i"</td><td>"i"</td><td>"i"</td><td>"i"</td><td>"i"</td></tr>");
    $("#segmentTable").append(row);
    }
});
});
</script>

<select id="noOfSegments">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

and #segmentTable is my table id
but the above script gives me this error:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { "

Can anyone please suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a lot of parantheses, quotes and plus signs.
This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#noOfSegments").change(function(){
    var counter=$('#noOfSegments').val();
    for(i=0; i<counter; i++){
    var row = $("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + i + "</td></tr>");
    $("#segmentTable").after(row.html());
    }
});
});
```

Comment: .after(row.html()) does not append the row so its giving me a weird structure

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xzrxs/)

corrected code and

changed `$("#segmentTable").after(row.html())`

to

`$("#segmentTable").html(row.html());`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#noOfSegments").change(function () {
        var counter = $('#noOfSegments').val();
        for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            var row = $("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + i + "</td></tr>");
            $("#segmentTable").html(row.html());
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `${#noOfSegments}` to `$('#noOfSegments')`.

Answer (score 0):

In java script you can do pure dynamically

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.id = "tbldrp";
var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
var rowItems = row.insertCell(0);
var label = document.createElement("label");
label.id = "lblDripName";
label.innerHTML = "Label Content";
rowItems.appendChild(label);
```